# surjection from finite set X-Y

Tags: combinatorics

The surjection b is
$$ b: X \to Y $$

there$ X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $Y=\{a,b\}$

How many surjections of this type of function can you find?

I know that the function b is defined on the set to the left and its values in the set Y. The values of such function b determine a 4-tuple of elements of Y, and this 4-tuple belongs to the set $Y^4$. Each of the element of $Y^4$ is an 4-tuple and corresponds to a function b (as above) defined by the equations
$$f(1)=y_1, \ldots , f(4)=y_4.$$

So, of this we can see that the function $b$ is logically the same thing as an element of the product set $y^4$.

So, if $F$ denote the set of functions $b$, then the cardinality of $F$ should be
$$|F|=|Y^4|=|Y|^4=2^4$$

or am I wrong? The repetitions is allowed because surjections means that an element from the set $Y$ can be paired with at least one element from $X$, which means;

$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ BUT $x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$

If it was and injection then the solution should be $n(n-1)\cdots(n-(m-1))=4\cdot3$ just because a function is injective iff
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$$
which means that the repetitions is not allowed. Because if it is, we will count same function more than once.

**Question: Where am i doing wrong ?**

Comment: For a general answer, look at: [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that functions from $X \to Y$ are essentially the same as ordered quadruples, i.e. elements of $Y^4$.  Thus the *total* number of functions $X \to Y$ is $|Y|^4 = 2^4$.  But the number of *surjective functions only* is less.

A surjective function has to "cover" the entire set $Y$.  Thus there are two ordered quadruples that are not allowed: $(a,a,a,a)$ and $(b,b,b,b)$, which do not cover both of $a$ and $b$.  Thus the total number of surjections is not $2^4$, but $2^4 - 2 = 14$.

Your reasoning about the number of injections looks correct.  In particular, the number of injections $X \to Y$ is indeed $2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 \cdot -1 = 0$, and the number of injections $Y \to X$ is indeed $4 \cdot 3 = 12$.

Comment: (a,a,a,a) and (b,b,b,b) is not allowed just because the element in Y must have atleast one original-element, right?

Comment: @Kim Yes, if you mean what I think you mean by "original-element".  Each element of $Y$ has to be equal to $f(x)$ for some $x \in X$.

Comment: Yes i meant that. I appreciate your help. This site is really good to getting help, and help other people.

Thanks alot!